# How to check (simulate), how much space will be freed after I remove a btrfs subvolume?

Tags: disk-usage, btrfs

The question is not trivial. BTRFS is COW file system and one object stored on hard disk can be referenced by many files.

I use BTRFS snapshots as a part of a backup solution on my production server. This way I have space-efficient, browsable history of a given subvolume (I use a modification of the [SnapBtr](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/SnapBtr)).

I have several independent btrfs subvolumes for different purposes and a backup scheme for each one. When the free space is running out, I can get the most unneeded backup snapshot from each backup pool based on the smart logarithmic-time-cost algorithm of `SnapBtr`.

I need a way to weight the amount of data that will be freed after I remove each backup with age of the old snapshot and importance of its backup pool. 
I am missing the former information.

I understand that the process of calculation of the free space on the BTRFS is neither trivial nor quick. I need something that would simulate the subvolume's deletion to get the size of the would-be freed space.

Can anyone help me? Should I post this message to the `linux-btrfs@vger.kernel.org`?

Answer (score 7):

As demonstrated [here](http://dustymabe.com/2013/09/22/btrfs-how-big-are-my-snapshots/), this is actually fairly simple to do.

First, enable btrfs quotas:

```
# btrfs quota enable /btrfs_subvolume
```

And then run:

```
# btrfs qgroup show /btrfs_subvolume
OR
# btrfs qgroup show -f /btrfs_subvolume
```

Which in Btrfs v3.18.2 shows you this:

```
qgroupid        rfer       excl
--------        ----       ----
0/260        1.09GiB    1.09GiB
```

The 0/260 is the subvolume ID, and the excl is the exclusive data in the subvolume. If you delete the subvolume, that's how much space you'll free up.

Edit: According to this [link](https://github.com/openSUSE/snapper/issues/51), this appears to be the official recommended way to do this.

Comment: [Pro Backup](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/17560/pro-backup) pointed out (in a suggested edit) that it’s worth checking the [known issues with quota support](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Quota_support#Known_issues).

Answer (score 0):

[`btrfsQuota.py`](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Quota_support#.2Fusr.2Flocal.2Fbin.2FbtrfsQuota.py) makes the output of `btrfs qgroup show` more readable, replacing subvol IDs with the names of the subvols, e.g.:

```
subvol                                      group         total    unshared
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
test/a                                      0/970        20.05M       0.05M
test/b                                      0/971        20.05M      10.05M
test/c                                      0/972        30.05M      10.05M
test/d                                      0/973        30.05M       0.05M
test/e                                      0/974        30.05M      10.05M
```

Comment: It doesn't work with default btrfs-tools version of Ubuntu 14.04. You need to install a newer one, and then everything is ok

Comment: @AdamRyczkowski I'm using the Python 3 version of that script now, and it works fine.